# What general purpose functions do you use really often that aren't in the standard library?

Tags: haskell

It can be your own or from other libraries. Many from this google talk are pretty nifty:
https://github.com/mtnviewmark/haskell-amuse-bouche

Comment: On SO, many people discourage polls, as they don't fit well into the Q&A principle of SO. You may poll on `haskell-cafe@haskell.org` if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that with "standard library" you mean the *base* library:

- `deepseq` (`Control.DeepSeq`, *deepseq*),
- `diffUTCTime` (`Data.Time.Clock`, *time*),
- `liftIO` (`Control.Monad.IO.Class`, *transformers*).

Not to list every single function, i use these modules and libraries a lot:

- `Control.Concurrent.STM` (*stm*),
- `Control.Exception.Control` (*monad-control*),
- `Data.Vector` (yes, indeed the boxed one, *vector*),
- `Data.VectorSpace` (*vector-space*).

A library of my own used in almost all of my projects is the *netwire* AFRP library.